# Oracle APEX Set value to Page Item from Ajax process

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I'm trying to upload document from APEX page to S3 bucket and I'm successful with the help of plugin from https://www.apexutil.com/ords/prod/f?p=700:200:1349309139567:::::

The plugin demonstrate retrieve the upload result and inserting to table as explained below.

```
Create new dynamic action;
Choose Upload Success [FM Component];
Choose "Execute JavaScript Code" action;
Inside the "Code" textarea define code:

apex.server.process("my_ajax_process", {
x01: this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.serverId,
x02: this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.file.name,
x03: this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.file.body.size,
x04: this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.file.body.type
}, {
success: function() {
console.log("success");
},
```

and retrieve the x0 values in Ajax process and inserting to table.

```
Create Ajax Process, name: "my_ajax_process"
Define PL/SQL code:

declare
l_server_id varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x01;
l_name varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x02;
l_size number := apex_application.g_x03;
l_type varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x04;
begin
insert into MY_TABLE (MT_SERVER_ID, MT_NAME, MT_SIZE, MT_TYPE)
values (l_server_id, l_name, l_size, l_type);
owa_util.status_line(nstatus => 204, creason => 'No Content');
end;
```

However I need to capture the X0 values in the Ajax process and assign to Form pages items, as I have to store the output along with other form fields and store into my table. I have tried and however its not getting updated. Any help much appreciated

```
declare
l_server_id varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x01;
l_name varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x02;
l_size number := apex_application.g_x03;
l_type varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x04;
begin
:P12_DOCUMENTURL := l_server_id;
:P12_DOCUMENTTYPE := l_type;
:P12_DOCSIZE := l_size;
owa_util.status_line(nstatus => 204, creason => 'No Content');
end;
```

Comment: How have you verified that it's not working? For P12_DOCUMENTURL, do you see a Maintain Session State setting under Source? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: Its set to Per Request. I expect to see the input item should display the data (x01) once the document is uploaded, however its blank and in the table its inserted as null

Comment: You said, "once the document is uploaded". However, updating session state is not the same thing as updating the DOM/web page. If you want the values to be displayed on the page, you need to either: a) refresh the page (that would rerender it using the values in session state) or b) bring the values back to the DOM as part of the Ajax call and them map them to the correct items in the page. I recommend option b.

Answer (score 1):

:P12_DOCUMENTURL := l_server_id; -- This kind of assignment wont work in an ajax process

But you can use APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE

```
BEGIN
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('my_item','myvalue');
END;
```

Example

```
BEGIN
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P12_DOCUMENTURL',l_server_id);
END;
```

More details here - 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-62AA4333-160D-44FD-9F07-D188A2F4BC55.htm#AEAPI181

Also please take a look at this https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2014/02/apex_util-set_session_state-may-or-may-not-commit/

For some more discussion about the commits issued.

Comment: I have tried the same with and without explicit COMMIT, still no luck. 

declare
l_server_id varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x01;
l_name varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x02;
l_size number := apex_application.g_x03;
l_type varchar2(4000) := apex_application.g_x04;
begin
APEX_UTIL.set_session_state('P12_DOCUMENTURL',l_server_id);
:P12_DOCUMENTTYPE := l_type;
:P12_DOCSIZE := l_size;
owa_util.status_line(nstatus => 204, creason => 'No Content');

COMMIT;
end;

Comment: @aaludra, Are you checking the session or the item on the page? The item on the page will show the old value. Only the session state will show the new value.

Comment: Looking for the page item to get updated with value. How to get the value from session state? the goal is show the output to the users after successful file upload

Comment: You can just update it from the javascript function using -- apex.item('P12_DOCUMENTURL').setValue(this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.serverId);

Answer (score 1):

Finally this works for me.

A dynamic action

```
var l01 = this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.serverId;
var l03 = this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.file.body.size;
var l04 = this.browserEvent.originalEvent.detail.file.body.type;
apex.server.process 
( "upload_ajax_process", 
    {},
    { success: function( pData ) {
         $s("P12_DOCUMENTURL",l01 );  
         $s("P12_DOCSIZE", l03);  
         $s("P12_DOCUMENTTYPE", l04);  
      }
    }
);
```

Also  Ajax process "upload_ajax_process" with some dummy statement. Without this I'm getting "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0"

```
begin
  owa_util.status_line(nstatus => 204, creason => 'No Content');
end;
```